# What does IN ACCESS EXCLUSIVE MODE do in Rails migration?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration

My understanding is that you want to lock the table so that users can't be making changes to its rows while you want to update something. For example, if you want to update all your posts that used to have an empty body to say "write something here" instead, then you want to lock those rows up while this migration is running. I'm not sure what the `IN ACCESS EXCLUSIVE MODE` does though.
`execute 'LOCK TABLE table_name IN ACCESS EXCLUSIVE MODE;'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`access exclusive` mode prevents any other process from even reading from the table, not just writing to it. If you're running migration it must be safer to lock tables like with mode like this one, to prevents records damage while migration running.